# How to avoid extra output from this java code

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, return

Please Note: Please do not just click this question as negative before going through it carefully.

**Input:**

```
int[] rani = {0,1,2,3,0,0,1,1,0,0};
int[] um = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

**Output required:**

```
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0
```

**Output generated:**

```
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 2 0 0 0 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0
```

I need only the last line from the 5 lines of the above output. Being new to programming and java, I need help to get only the last line as output.

The complete code is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RaniMsc {

    public static void doPrint(int[] tt, String varnan) {   
        System.out.printf("\n%s ", varnan); 
        for (int q : tt) {
             System.out.printf("%d ", q);   
        } 
    }

    public static void rangeSetValue(int[] foo, int index_1, int index_2) { 
        for(int i = index_1; i < index_2; i++) {
            foo[i]=index_2-index_1;

            doPrint(foo, "This is for Matra Processing ");  
        }  
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] rani = {0,1,2,3,0,0,1,1,0,0};
        int[] um = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i <rani.length) {
            if (rani[i] != 0) {
                j = i;  
                while (i < rani.length) {
                    if (rani[i] == 0) {
                        k=i;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    } 
                }   
                rangeSetValue(um, j, k);   
            } else {
                i++;
            }  
        } 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the output printed just once, call the method that prints the output just once, after the loop :

```
  for(int i=index_1; i<index_2; i++)  {
      foo[i]=index_2-index_1;
   }
   doPrint(foo, "This is for Matra Processing ");
```

EDIT:

I can't say I understand what's the purpose of the loops in the main method, but since you are calling `rangeSetValue` more than once, you get more than one output line.

You can move the call to the method that prints the output to the main method.

i.e. :

Don't print anything here :

```
public static void rangeSetValue(int[] foo, int index_1, int index_2) { 
    for(int i = index_1; i < index_2; i++) {
        foo[i]=index_2-index_1;
    }  
}
```

Print the output at the end of your main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] rani = {0,1,2,3,0,0,1,1,0,0};
    int[] um = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i <rani.length) {
        if (rani[i] != 0) {
            j = i;  
            while (i < rani.length) {
                if (rani[i] == 0) {
                    k=i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    i++;
                } 
            }   
            rangeSetValue(um, j, k);   
        } else {
            i++;
        }  
    } 
    doPrint(um, "This is for Matra Processing "); // print the output here
}
```

Comment: After doing it I am getting two lines: 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 
This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0

Comment: @Garry That's not possible (unless you are calling `rangeSetValue` more than once).

Comment: Hi Respected Eran, after making your suggested correction I am getting two lines but I need only  and only the last one:This is for Matra Processing  0 3 3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0  . Kindly give some detailed hint to achieve that.

Comment: Hey, You can remove the "doPrint" from for loop and add after the loop as  done above. You are calling the method "rangeSetValue" more than once so it prints it twice.